# Use plan and quantity to add customer using stripe

Tags: php, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I created a customer and charge that customer by using amount instead of plan. I checked their documentation but have no idea how to do that. Can anyone help me with my below code,

```
// create customer
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
  "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
  "description" => "This is testing mode",
  "email" => "test@mail.com",
));


// Charge the Customer
Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 3000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer->id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, and follows that outlined here:

https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

Is there a specific question or problem you're having?

Best,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.